# Find and delete unused accounts from my Google+ circles

Tags: google-plus

How can I know which friends on Google+ are not using it? I have reached the limit in some circles, and want to delete the users who are in my circles but don't use Google+.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Circloscope](https://plus.google.com/115932955064831083806/posts/4Mpw2E5kXKe) Premium for **Chrome**: 5 AUD for the extension and your circles management will be a piece of cake.

Circloscope premium lets you analyze people in your circles in numerous ways. For example, you can:

- analyze the last post of all people in your circles (or a specific circle or mix of circles),
- analyze your relationship with them (whether it's a two-way relationship, you're a follower, or they're your followers),
- analyze their engagement with your posts (either by plussing, resharing or commenting on your posts),
- analyze their relevance to you (based on how many interactions between you and them), etc.

I hope this helps, it sure has worked for me.